# pip install from wheel and repository

Tags: python, python-3.x, build, pip, python-wheel

I'm trying to install some packages via wheel. There are some requirements for which the wheel packages haven't been built. I want pip to search a local directory that contains wheels first and only if it can't find them there to  then download those packages.

I'm using:

```
pip install --no-index --find-links=/tmp -r requirements.txt
```

to run my installation, however it just checks the wheel-dir `/tmp` and then doesn't bother to download and install those packages for which we don't have wheels. The reason for that is because we're using `--no-index`.

Is there any alternative so that it checks wheel first and then download if wheel doesn't exist?

I've checked the documentation but couldn't find anything.

Comment: You can try something like this `python -m pip install https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/42/1e/5b6608faf3462cb0b396fe4c19a8a1fb690e3a0f4b03d34174c16774a98c/pygame-1.9.4-cp27-cp27m-win32.whl`

Comment: well that's just a wheel file being installed from a remote location. Please read my question again.

Comment: _Is there any alternative so that it checks wheel first and then download if wheel doesn't exist?_ Why then not leave `--no-index` out?

Comment: @hoefling: Because once `--no-index` is out of the way, pip doesn't check the local wheels. It simply starts download from the remote links.

Comment: I can't reproduce this behaviour; although `pip` does indeed _search_ for packages available on PyPI, it doesn't download them if a suitable version is found in the local dir. Only versions not found locally are downloaded.

Comment: @hoefling:  _Only versions not found locally are downloaded_ : Do you mean the .whl packages not found locally will be downloaded from PyPI ?  I tired on pip 9.0.3 and pip 18.0 but can see the behaviour is same.

Comment: Yes; run the command with `--verbose` flag to see details of analyzing and selecting packages. In the output, grep for `Local files found:` to see what local packages are selected for installation.

Comment: The default impl of `pip` [prefers local files (`file_versions`) over download links (`page_versions`)](https://github.com/pypa/pip/blob/master/src/pip/_internal/index.py#L443). So it's either that you have some custom `pip` version patched e.g. by a distro maintainer, or the actual wheels downloaded locally don't match the requirements.